maas-packer can't install 'gnome' package on RHEL9 and sles15
I tried modifying http/rhel9.ks.pkrtpl.hcl with package @^graphical-server-environment get messages: 'The installation was stopped due to an error which occurred while running in non-interactive cmdline mode. Since there cannot be any questions in cmdline mode, edit your kickstart file and retry installation.'
cdrom
poweroff
firewall --enabled --service=ssh
firstboot --disable
ignoredisk --only-use=vda
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard us
network --device eth0 --bootproto=dhcp
firewall --disabled --service=ssh
selinux --enforcing
timezone UTC --isUtc
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder="vda" --timeout=1
rootpw --plaintext 111111
user --name="test" --password=111111
eula --agreed

repo --name="AppStream" ${KS_APPSTREAM_REPOS} ${KS_PROXY}

zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
part / --size=1 --grow --asprimary --fstype=ext4

%post --erroronfail
# workaround anaconda requirements and clear root password
#passwd -d root
#passwd -l root

# Clean up install config not applicable to deployed environments.
for f in resolv.conf fstab; do
    rm -f /etc/$f
    touch /etc/$f
    chown root:root /etc/$f
    chmod 644 /etc/$f
done

rm -f /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-[^lo]*

# Kickstart copies install boot options. Serial is turned on for logging with
# Packer which disables console output. Disable it so console output is shown
# during deployments
sed -i 's/^GRUB_TERMINAL=.*/GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"/g' /etc/default/grub
sed -i '/GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial"/d' /etc/default/grub
sed -ri 's/(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=".*)\s+console=ttyS0(.*")/\1\2/' /etc/default/grub
sed -i 's/GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=.*/GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=false/g' /etc/default/grub

dnf clean all
%end

%packages
@^graphical-server-environment
bash-completion
cloud-init
# cloud-init only requires python3-oauthlib with MAAS. As such upstream
# removed this dependency.
python3-oauthlib
rsync
tar
# grub2-efi-x64 ships grub signed for UEFI secure boot. If grub2-efi-x64-modules
# is installed grub will be generated on deployment and unsigned which breaks
# UEFI secure boot.
grub2-efi-x64
efibootmgr
shim-x64
dosfstools
lvm2
mdadm
device-mapper-multipath
iscsi-initiator-utils
-plymouth
# Remove Intel wireless firmware
-i*-firmware
%end


I also tried @gnome-desktop with the same failure.
I think packer cannot recognize gnome because I also reported an error after adding gnome in suse15.
But there is no such information on the Internet and no one has asked similar questions.
If anyone would help me I’d be grateful as I’ve been trying for three days

Unfortunately, Stack Overflow isn't the right place for your question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit.
